# link front end files HTML, CSS , JS to the backend node.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, express

I am new to web development  and I recently had an online course about node.js and express  . 
The course doesn't really cover how you can add your HTML , CSS , and JS file when using Node.

I have tried this :

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express ();
var port= 3000;

app.use(express.static('public'));
app.listen(port,function(){
console.log('Express app listening on port' +port);
})

app.get('/hello',function(request,response){
response.sendfile('index.html')
})
```

In this server.Js file , I pointed to the HTML file that is should load on that page . 
It loads the page , however , with no style and it didn't load the images in it ...

What should be done in order to make my front end files available when called ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you miss to link `CSS` file in your `index.html` file

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
```

assuming your folder Structure is:

```
project root 
     ├── server.js
     ├── package.json 
     └── public   
       ├── css  
         └── style.css
       ├── index.html
```

Comment: Correct ! I missed creating the public folder . Thank you